# How do I properly install drivers for an Intel ARC dedicated GPU to make it work for OpenGL?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel, opengl

I tried following the steps at https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/driver/client/overview.html (external link) but got nowhere, as the output from
`glxinfo`
Results in
`OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)`
, my intigrated GPU.  I'm trying to get my Arc A750 dedicated GPU to be the OpenGL/Vulkan renderer, how can I make this happen?
Computer specs:
Intel Core i5-6500 CPU/Intel Intigrated Graphics 530
Intel ARC A750 Dedicated GPU
12 GB DDR4 RAM```

Comment: Another thing I noticed so far: according to lspci, my integrated GPU is being used for rendering while the ARC A750 is used for VGA-compatible output!  This means that OpenGL is definitely rendering on the integrated GPU! Output from `lspci | grep -E "VGA|Display"`:
`00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
          03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 56a1 (rev 08)`

Comment: Try `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo`

Comment: I tried running your command, but the output from `glxinfo` later states that the renderer is still my integrated GPU.  I believe this as I get no FPS and my A750's fan don't even start to spin, indicating no processes being run.  Thank you for your comment though :)